# Permanent redirect with Next.js middleware

Tags: redirect, next.js, middleware

I need to handle large sum of permanent redirects with Next.js and I try to use Next.js middleware to set them up. I have a JSON file with all redirects and my middleware is as follows:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import redirectsJson from '../redirects.json'

export default function middleware(req) {
  const url = req.nextUrl;
  let start = Date.now();

  // Find the redirect from the local JSON file, do note this JSON shouldn't be
  // large, as the space in Edge Middleware is quite limited
  const localRedirect = (redirectsJson)[url.pathname];
  if (localRedirect) {
    url.pathname = localRedirect.destination;
    url.searchParams.set('l', `${Date.now() - start}`);
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }
}
```

Here is my example JSON file:

```
{
    "/about": {
        "destination": "/about-us",
        "permanent": true
    }
}
```

When entering `/about` it loads correctly the content of `/about-us` page. But the problem is there is no 301 status and URL stays at `/about`. Link trace shows this:

[image]

Is this all correct for permanent redirect or whould the site properly be redirected to `/about-us`?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect function takes a 2nd parameter (number) so you can pass it through like this

```
return NextResponse.redirect(url, 301);
```